# .trigger('click') not working on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code :

```
$("#full-year td").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

and for some reason the .trigger('click') will only fire for the first td the cursor lands on and none of the other td's.

Here is a working example using .toggleClass instead of .trigger.

https://jsfiddle.net/bx5zbor5/2/

Here is an example of it not working.(Notice how it fires on the first td it lands on)

https://jsfiddle.net/Lym9wmaf/5/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you want on `click`? `only fire for the first td` how do you identify?

Comment: When I use your fiddle, `.toggleClass` seems to work on every `td` correctly.

Comment: @Wolf exactly what he said in his post. It works with toggleClass but he would like it to work with trigger (which only works on the first td)

Comment: This code works fine in your fiddle : 
`$("#our_table td").mouseenter(function () {
      $(this).on('click', function() {
                console.log('a');
            });
            $(this).trigger('click');
        });`

Comment: You have to Have the trigger event, for instance `$('#td').click(function() { ... });` or `$('#td).on('click, function() { ... });`

Comment: Did you add a listener on the 'click' event ?

Comment: Try using `$('#out_table_id').click(...)` instead of `$('#out_table_id').on('click'...)`

Comment: @Manwal I was logging this to console. console.log(this);

Comment: @StJohnRussell where you are using `console`. Take a look on my answer and see its triggering or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have appended the td with a `#` (check the selector: `$("#td")`), meaning you're selecting a table cell with the ID `td`, which is not every table cell.

Change the selector to: `$('td')`

-- edit --
Seems to work though... Checkout https://jsfiddle.net/bx5zbor5/7/

Comment: It was editing mistake. Originally it is `$("#full-year td")`.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you.

```
$("#our_table td").mouseenter(function (evt) {
            $(evt.currentTarget).toggleClass("highlighted");
            $(evt.currentTarget).trigger("click");
        }).click(function(evt){
    console.log($(evt.currentTarget).html());
});
```

[Sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/eshugoel24/uv59p247/)

Please let me know if you will face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor will never land on any of `td` element because td is not editable element.

Take a look on following `trigger` is working for every element:

```
$("#our_table td").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).trigger('click');
});

$("#our_table td").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
})
```

[**Updated DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bx5zbor5/8/)

Whenever mouse enter on any of `td` it `console` its text.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$('#full_year id').click(function(){ //foo });`

Instead of

`$('#full_year id').on('click', function(){ //foo });`

as you put it in the comments.
https://api.jquery.com/click/
Says here that the event will bind to the click, while at 
https://api.jquery.com/on/
simply says it adds a listener, doesn't bind the actualy event.